# $\forall a, b≥0$. Then $(a+b)^{p}≤2^{p-1}(a^{p}+b^{p})$, for $p≥1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**My try:**

We have to show that

$$(a+b)^{p}≤2^{p-1}(a^{p}+b^{p}).$$

As $a≤max(a, b)$ and $b≤max(a, b)$. Then

$a+b≤max(a, b)+max(a, b)$

$=2max(a, b)$

And so that

$(a+b)^{p}≤[2(max(a, b))]^{p}$

$=2^{p}(max(a, b))^{p}$

$≤2^{p}max(a^{p}, b^{p})$

$2(a+b)^{p}≤2^{p}(a^{p}+b^{p})$

$(a+b)^{p}≤2^{p-1}(a^{p}+b^{p})$

Pls tell me if it is correct. Correction will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have proved a weaker inequality.

Comment: Ok I don't know itss name.

Comment: You did not prove what you are asked to prove.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy missed one of the $2^p$s... thx.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by " But I have sufficed it with that equality like it is enough to prove as what I have done. – ", sorry.

Comment: Your first step is wrong. It is *not* sufficient to prove $(a+b)^p \leq 2^p(a^p+b^p)$.

Comment: _You_ need to give an explanation of _why_ it suffices to prove the modified inequality. (It doesn't.)

Comment: How about now sir. I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is now correct, after the edits. I will sketch an alternative proof here. An obvious route to pursue is induction. Take base case $p=1$, and your statement is obviously true. Now, assume, for some $p=k$,
$$(a+b)^k\leq 2^{k-1}(a^k+b^k)......(1)$$
Then, to prove $p=k+1$, take the identity:
$$(a-b)(a^k-b^k)\geq 0$$
This means $$a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}\geq a b^k+b a^k.....(2)$$
Now we have, for $p=k+1$,
$$(a+b)^{k+1}=(a+b)(a+b)^k\leq 2^{k-1}(a+b)(a^k+b^k)=2^{k-1}(a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}+ a b^k+b a^k)\leq 2^{k-1}(a^{k+1}+ b^{k+1} +a^{k+1} +b^{k+1})         [From (2)]$$
This means statement is true for $p=k+1$ too, hence it has been proved by induction.

Comment: Pls check now. I have edited. And I don't want to use induction. So tell me is it okay now?

Comment: No it is still not correct. How did $2(a+b)^p\leq 2^p(a^p+b^p)$ follow from $(a+b)^p\leq 2^p max(a^p, b^p)$?

Comment: Also, what's the problem with using induction?

Comment: $$(a+b)^{p}≤2^{p}(a^{p}), (a+b)^{p}≤2^{p}(b^{p})$$ by adding we will get first inequality as you have written above.

Comment: Second, this is a fact that if $ a, b≥0$ and $p≥1$, then $$(max(a, b))^{p}≤max(a^{p}, b^{p})$$. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You are right, now.

Comment: So is my proof okay now?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to say that.

Comment: Ok thank you sir. Actually, I had proved like that before but I had just forgot. That's why I  just didn't want to use induction.