# Prove with induction $(a+b+c)^k\leq 3^{k-1} (a^k+b^k+c^k)$

Tags: inequality, induction

> If $a,b,c \geq 0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ then $${(a+b+c)^k\over 3^k}\leq {a^k+b^k+c^k\over 3}$$

Proof: Using Holder inequality $$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_iy_i|\leq (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{1\over p}(\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^q)^{1\over q}$$ where $1/p+1/q=1$ we get it setting $p=k$, $n=3$, $y_i=1$ and $x_1=a,x_2=b,x_3=c$.

Now how to prove it in more elementary fashion, say with induction?

Comment: Note that the inequality holds for all real numbers $a, b, c$, not only for non-negative ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proof with induction one needs to show that
$$
 (a^k+b^k+c^k)(a+b+c) \le 3 (a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}+c^{k+1})
$$
and that is true by the [Chebyshev sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) or by noting that
$$
3 (a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}+c^{k+1}) - (a^k+b^k+c^k)(a+b+c) \\
= (a^k-b^k)(a-b) + (b^k-c^k)(b-c) + (c^k- a^k)(c-a) \ge 0 
$$
(inspired by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4149520/42969 ).

An elementary proof without induction would be to apply Jensen's inequality to the convex function $t \mapsto t^k$.